# Native calendar issue

Tags: iphone, ios

How to fetch events from native calendar with minimum delay, i don't ask about the code of fetching events, i ask about the performance of fetching and best way to enhance it?

Comment: What did you mean by your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enhance performance You can use predicates to minimize the number of events that match predicates